# Why there is no timer metrics in Flink to record the processing time of specific methods in Operator. [Apache Flink - 1.12.2]

Tags: apache-flink, metrics

As i can see flink metrics like meter, counter etc in flink documentation. But there is no timer metrics to record the processing time of particular method in Operator or to record the processing time for data based on the key (kafka as source).
Is there is alternative to timer in Flink metrics ?

Comment: For that sort of insight, using a profiler can be helpful. Since Flink 1.13, there is also built-in support for flame graphs. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/debugging/flame_graphs/

Comment: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/metrics/#end-to-end-latency-tracking

Comment: I have the same question. The Flink flame graphs and end to end latency tracing are great, but sometimes you need to measure other things, like the time taken to call an external database, so these can be reported to an external monitoring system and be monitored for spikes or what not in an automated fashion.